# How to use splice on string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I wish to use **splice** on string e.g.

```
console.log(removeFromString('Elie', 2, 2)) // 'El'
```

Comment: Please read this: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)

Comment: Start with the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods). `String.prototype.splice` won’t exist, because strings are immutable. Use `slice` or `substring` instead.

Comment: Hi ! And what is removeFromString() ? ;)

Comment: Method splice is linked to arrays not to strings.

Comment: You can use `subString` method

Comment: @AbinThaha There is no method called `subString`. You mean `substring`.

Comment: Dear Reporter, I know Method splice is linked to arrays not to strings, I wanted to is there any way so that splice can be used in string object.

Comment: @AbinThaha Please stop editing the question to fit your interpretation. And if you edit, at least don't break the formatting.

Comment: @AmrendraK If you know that `splice` can be used with arrays, why not make a character array, then splice, then convert back to a string? Again, start with the documentation, e.g. the [`Array` methods](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods). Try something on your own. All the tools you’ll need are documented there.

Comment: Dear Philippe removeFromString()  is function name where I passes string "Elie". Inside function I wish to use splice method

Comment: Ok, I just wrote a `debugEveryCodeSample()` but it doesn't work fine, could you tell me why ? ;)

Comment: @AmrendraK And what does `splice` _do_ to the string? Can you at least _try_ to describe the algorithm? Perhaps in terms of the method names provided in the documentation links? Perhaps even in the form of _code that you tried_?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the string to an array, invoke `splice()` on the array, and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the results back together:

```js
const removeFromString = (s, x, y) => {
  const array = [...s];
  array.splice(x, y);
  return array.join('');
}

console.log(removeFromString('Elie', 2, 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not a great way but this is just to give you idea how things works in javascript.

1. You can't use splice on a string because it works for arrays as *it doesn’t work on strings because strings are immutable* (edit after
   [Sebastian Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon)'s comment)
2. You can use `split` method to convert a string into array of characters.
3. You can use `splice` method on array of characters.
4. You can use `join` method to convert array of characters to make a string

```js
let stringTitle = "Elie";   // string
let stringArray = stringTitle.split("");   // spliting string into array of characters
console.log(stringArray);
let subString = stringArray.splice(0,2).join("")  // using splice on array of characters and then join them to make a string
console.log(subString)  // output El
```

I would suggest using `str.substring(0, 2);` for this use case is a better option.

```js
let stringExample = "Elie";
let substring = stringExample.substring(0, 2);
console.log(substring) // output El
```

Comment: _“You can't use splice on a string because it works for arrays.”_ — This reasoning is not quite correct, or at least not complete. Mainly, it doesn’t work on strings because strings are immutable. You can totally attempt to do `Array.prototype.splice.call("abc", 1, 0)`, but you’ll get an error whose cause is the string’s immutability. Also, the `split`–`splice`–`join` approach has already been suggested, and my comment on the other answer still holds: `.split` is not Unicode-aware. Please use `Array.from` instead.

Comment: Thanks.. let me add this statement in the answer.

Comment: I already have mentioned this is just to give an idea. It is not a great approach. And, I didn't read your comment on the answer before posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do.

```js
function removeFromString(string, start, count) {
    let str = string.split('');
    str.splice(start, count);
    return str.join('');
}

console.log(removeFromString('Elie', 2, 2));
```

Comment: `.split('')` is not Unicode-aware. Please use `Array.from` to support a larger variety of characters.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes good approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function removeFromString(str, start, end) {
  let arr = Array.from(str);
  arr.splice(start, end);
  return arr.join(String());
}
```

and then use:

```
removeFromString('Elie', 2, 2);
```

Comment: `String()` really isn’t best practice. Use `""` instead.

Comment: "" - is a hardcode

Comment: Uh, yes, so is `String()`. That’s what you want in `.join`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code
you can get more info about slice [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp)

```
let str = "Elie";
// pass start and end position to slice method ,it will not include end character like i is at 2nd position
console.log(str.slice(0, 2));
```